# I can't set a cookie on my localhost from my server with a (sub)domain api.localhost in NodeJS/Express

Tags: express, cookies, cors

I am trying to set a cookie as a session ID on my website inside NodeJS/Express. But I can only set the cookie to my domain "api.localhost", not just "localhost"

This is my where I set my cookie. I have a domain setting there, without the domain setting, it sets my cookie to "api.localhost". With it, it doesn't set it at all unless it is "api.localhost", so I can't set it to ".apihost" or any other localhost with a subdomain.

```
function sendCookie(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.session = crypto.randomUUID();

  res.cookie("sid", res.locals.session, {
    domain: ".localhost",
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + 900000000),
  });
  next();
}
```

This is my cors.

```
import cors from "cors";
app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: "localhost:3000",
  })
);
```

What is causing this and how do I fix it?